# R List subsetting using "[[" shows error subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, sapply, purrr

I was trying to subset a large list with 278226 elements and each element (shown as below) is also a list which has a number(between 39 and 50) of sub-elements(size 1 atomic vector with different names).

```
> str(listings_England[9922])
List of 1
 $ listing:List of 40
  ..$ agent_address       : chr "35 John Street, Luton"
  ..$ agent_logo          : chr "https://st.zoocdn.com/zoopla_static_agent_logo_(257607).png"
  ..$ agent_name          : chr "Ashton Carter Homes"
  ..$ agent_phone         : chr "020 8115 4543"
  ..$ category            : chr "Residential"
  ..$ country             : NULL
  ..$ country_code        : chr "gb"
  ..$ county              : NULL
  ..$ displayable_address : chr "Hatters Way Luton, Luton LU1"
  ..$ first_published_date: chr "2017-11-16 17:25:36"
  ..$ last_published_date : chr "2018-01-29 18:40:52"
  ..$ latitude            : chr "51.88188"
  ..$ listing_id          : chr "39336869"
  ..$ listing_status      : chr "sale"
  ..$ longitude           : chr "-0.43237194"
```

Then I extract sub-elements such as "*listing_id*" as below:

```
> id1 <- sapply(listings_England, "[[", "listing_id")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
> id3 <- sapply(listings_England[1:100000], "[[", "listing_id")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
> id2 <- sapply(listings_England[1:50000], "[[", "listing_id")
> 

> listings_England$listing_id
NULL
>
```

As you can see, it only works for the last one (same problem for the **purrr::map** family functions). I was wondering if it the limitation of these functions. And my current solution is:

```
id <- sapply(listings_England, function(x) x["listing_id"]) %>% as.numeric()
```

**The problem here is "[[" or "$" function is not working for this large list, and only "[" works.**

Comment: If it works for elements `1:50000` but not `1:100000`, **I bet** there's an element between in the `50000:100000` range that doesn't have a `listing_id` property, or the whole thing is `NULL`.

Comment: @JesseTweedle Yes, you are right! It's NULL causing this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Lists are annoying, and big ones are worse bc they toss out weird errors that don't point you in the right direction. If I can, I usually try to convert them to tibbles as soon as I can (either with `enframe` or `bind_rows` either directly or in some combination with `map`).

Comment: Oh, two more suggestions: just `bind_rows(listings_England)` right away, or maybe `purrr:discard(listings_England, is.null)` to drop `NULL` elements right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the “Missing/out of bounds indices" problem, [ and [[ differ slightly in their behaviour when the index is out of bounds (OOB). Details can be found in the "Advanced R" book section 4.3.3 (the following link)
[https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#subsetting-operators]

Answer (score 1):

As @JesseTweedle comments, your issue is a data-specific one. Somewhere in your data object *listing_id* does not exist as a named element and hence errs out. Consider wrapping your `sapply` function in a `tryCatch` to return NAs for those elements without *listing_id* with either `[[` or `$`:

```
id2 <- sapply(listings_England[1:100000], function(x) 
                 tryCatch(x[["listing_id"]],
                          warning = function(w) return(NA),
                          error = function(e) return(NA)
                 )
       )
```

Additionally, per your post it looks like you have a nested structure with a named *listing*. Try this:

```
id2 <- sapply(listings_England[1:100000], function(x) 
                 tryCatch(x$listing$listing_id,
                          warning = function(w) return(NA),
                          error = function(e) return(NA)
                 )
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the `listing_id` entry to numeric, just use `as.numeric` directly:

```
listings_England$listing_id <- as.numeric(listings_England$listing_id)
```

`sapply` is what you would use if you wanted to apply a function to each element across a vector.  But since `as.numeric` is already vectorized, you don't need an apply function in this case.

Comment: I want to extract all "listing_id" from all 278226 elements from this large list and saved in a vector, not convert to numeric, actually don't care if it is numeric or char.

Comment: @YunlongHuang `listings_England$listing_id` already gives you a vector with 278226 elements.  I'm not sure what you are asking for here.

Comment: What does `class(listings_England)` show you?  Size has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: > class(listings_England)
[1] "list"

Comment: The reason I think the size is the problem is because I have another smaller size list with no such problem.

Comment: Post a reproducible sample in your question.  I can't reproduce your observations locally, the `$` operator works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have what I would call a "nested list". You can see from the str output that there is only one item at the top of your "element tree". Try this:

```
id1 <- sapply(listings_England[[1]], "[[", "listing_id")
```

It then extracts the first item (which has all of the content) and works on the resulting list. Could also use the equivalent operation:

```
id1 <- sapply(listings_England$listing, "[[", "listing_id")
```